# Display record count in listbox using multiple tables and fields

Tags: drop-down-menu, count, record

i need help with a query, can't get it to work correctly. What i'm trying to achieve is to have a select box displaying the number of records associated with a particular theme, for some theme it works well for some it displays (0) when infact there are 2 records, I'm wondering if someone could help me on this, your help would be greatly appreciated, please see below my actual query + table structure :

```
SELECT theme.id_theme, theme.theme, calender.start_date,
      calender.id_theme1,calender.id_theme2, calender.id_theme3, COUNT(*) AS total 
FROM theme, calender 
WHERE (YEAR(calender.start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE()) 
    AND MONTH(calender.start_date) > MONTH(CURDATE()) ) 
    AND (theme.id_theme=calender.id_theme1) 
    OR (theme.id_theme=calender.id_theme2) 
    OR (theme.id_theme=calender.id_theme3) 
GROUP BY theme.id_theme 
ORDER BY theme.theme ASC
```

THEME table

```
|---------------------|
| id_theme | theme    |
|----------|----------|
|     1    |   Yoga   |
|     2    |   Music  |
|     3    |  Taichi  |
|     4    |  Dance   |
|     5    | Coaching |
|---------------------|
```

CALENDAR table

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id_calender | id_theme1 | id_theme2 | id_theme3 | start_date |  end_date  |
|-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|------------|------------|
|      1      |     2     |     4     |           | 2015-07-24 | 2015-08-02 |
|      2      |     4     |     1     |     5     | 2015-08-06 | 2015-08-22 |
|      3      |     1     |     3     |     2     | 2014-10-11 | 2015-10-28 |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

LISTBOX

```
|----------------|
|                |
|    Yoga (1)    |
|    Music (1)   |
|   Taichi (0)   |
|    Dance (2)   |
|  Coaching (1)  |
|----------------|
```

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that themes conditions should be into brackets

```
((theme.id_theme=calender.id_theme1) 
OR (theme.id_theme=calender.id_theme2) 
OR (theme.id_theme=calender.id_theme3))
```

Hope this help

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for answering, i've added the brackets and it's still the same result

Comment: I think that you should use many-to-many association for implementation many themes for calendar and your problem will be solved by join. In current implementation you must select all theme ids from calendar table and then use where statement.